# private method 'eval' called for Math:Module (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

I can not figure out how to use this method.  It seems really strange to me that it should be a private method within Math, as that would make it completely non-accessible for developers (as far as I can tell).  What am I missing?

My code is below:

```
str = "(5+9)/(3+4)"
puts Math.eval(str)
```

Comment: Only `eval` will work.. why calling on `Math`.. ? And yes it is `private` method. All `Kernel` module methods are private in Ruby. Private methods don't need explicit receiver..

Comment: @ArupRakshit - I think it's more accurate to say that private methods raise exceptions when they're called with an explicit receiver.  This restriction can be bypassed with the send method (e.g. `Math.send(:eval, str)`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure, what you are trying to achieve, but while `str` has a valid ruby syntax (the one from the example above has), here you go:

```
▶ str = "(5+9)/(3+4)"
#⇒ "(5+9)/(3+4)"
▶ instance_eval str
#⇒ 2
```